# Struts2 convention plugin (m2eclipse/geronimo)

Tags: struts2

Using convention-plugin seems really easy but im not able to make it work :(

I'm using struts2 version 2.2.3

I have a package named com.medicis.actions with a UserAction extending ActionSupport.
I don't have any struts.xml file
I have the convention-plugin depency set on my maven configuration (i also checked the generated war file)
There is my web.xml :

```
<display-name>Starter</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Filters -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>action2-cleanup</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>action2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>action2-cleanup</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>action2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Listeners -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jspSupportServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts2.views.JspSupportServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Welcome file lists -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I tried with and without the init param for the action2 filter:

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
   <param-value>com.medicis.actions</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I have this property set on my struts.propertie file :

> struts.action.extension=action

Still i'm unable to launch my action using localhost:8080/starter/user.action :

> There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name user

I really don't know what's going wrong, I even downloaded a simple example without any result either.

Could it be a configuration problem due to eclipse, m2eclipse, maven wtp or geronimo ???

If you need more information just tell me and i'll provide you that asap.

Comment: **[Config Browser Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/config-browser-plugin.html)**

Comment: Yes I use this plugin and it don't find any action neither...

Answer (score 1):

1. Create struts.properties in "src" folder
2. Copy and paste code from below:

   ```
   struts.convention.package.locators = actions
   struts.convention.action.suffix = Controller
   struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches = true
   ```
3. Create class called IndexController in com.example.actions
4. Copy and paste code from below:

   ```
   package com.example.actions;

   import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.SkipValidation;
   import org.apache.struts2.rest.DefaultHttpHeaders;
   import org.apache.struts2.rest.HttpHeaders;
   import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

   public class UserController extends ActionSupport {

       public String index(){
           return SUCCESS
       }

   }
   ```

You also need to create jsp file in WEB-INF/content/user/index.jsp